# Overlay images on the desktop with C++

Tags: c++, draw, desktop, layer

I am trying to make an interesting tutorial for a program I have developed, and I want arrows to appear and disappear on the screen at certain times of the tutorial. These arrows I have already drawn on paint (I can have them in png, jpg... practically any image format), but I have on idea on how to make them appear on the screen and disappear when I want them to.

Basically if they could appear on the screen, like on top of any other window, on the highest layer (with only the mouse itself capable of going over it), that would be my ideal code. It would not matter if print screen would include the image or not, all that matters is that it can appear and disappear when the right code is given.

Any help at all would leave me in your eternal debt xD!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to create a see-through and click-through fullscreen window that is always on top. Then you can draw the arrows in this window with GDI (assuming you're targeting Windows) at any position on-screen you like.

The window can be made see-through and click-through by using

```
WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
```

as extended window style.

Comment: Wow that is a really interesting approach, I will definitly take it into consideration. Another approach I saw online was to use the GetDC function, any thoughts on how that would go about?

Comment: Oh and there is a problem with the method stated. If I wanted to click something that is directly on the window, I would not be able to because of the window. Any way around that?

Comment: @rsthegreat12 That can be solved by using `WS_EX_LAYERED` in the extended window style.

Comment: @rsthegreat12, Don't use the screen's DC like it's your own. Use your own window.

Comment: @Overv; I am a bit of a noob when it comes to coding, but when I want to have my counsel program create a window, is there a specific function I can use? I know it is a noob question xD but I haven't been able to find out how to actually create that window after my program is already up and running.

Comment: @rsthegreat12 Yes, it's called [CreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx) :)

Comment: Heyy Overv, I am trying to do ur method :), to draw things on a window that is invisible and fully covers the screen. Hooweever, I am having troubles making the popup window. Here is the page with the code and problem I just made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331543/c-issue-with-creating-popup-window-getting-other-window-instead

Comment: @Overv hey dude, the WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, do I place them in the CreateWindow function somewhere or when I am declaring the window class, or where?

Comment: @rsthegreat12 Look up a Win32 tutorial.