# C++ Issue with creating popup window, getting other window instead

Tags: c++, api, popup, window

I am simply trying to make a pop up window, that later on will display whatever information i need it to. The issue I am having is... instead of creating a new popup window when I click the button, a copy of my main program window pops up.

Here is the code in my WinMain Function:

```
 HINSTANCE hInstanceSaved;//I am declaring an HINSTANCE VARIABLE HERE
 // SO THAT IT IS GLOBAL AND THEN I CAN USE IT WHEN I CREATE MY POPUP WINDOW

 INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
 {

hInstanceSaved = hInstance;
//here I am giving the global hInstanceSaved variable the value of hInstance
// so that when I click the button, I can have this variale available to me
// so that i can use the CreateWindowEx() function

MSG        Msg;
HWND       hWnd;
WNDCLASSEX WndClsEx;
LPCTSTR ClsName = "ResFund";
LPCTSTR WndName = "Resources Fundamentals";

// Create the application window
WndClsEx.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
WndClsEx.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
WndClsEx.lpfnWndProc   = WndProcedure;
WndClsEx.cbClsExtra    = 0;
WndClsEx.cbWndExtra    = 0;
WndClsEx.hIcon         = LoadIcon(hInstance,
                  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_BOOKED));
WndClsEx.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
WndClsEx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
WndClsEx.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
WndClsEx.lpszClassName = ClsName;
WndClsEx.hInstance     = hInstance;
WndClsEx.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(hInstance,
                  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_BOOKED));

// Register the application
RegisterClassEx(&WndClsEx);

// Create the window object
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
                      ClsName,
                      WndName,
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                      200,//CW_USEDEFAULT,//how much to the right
                      200, //CW_USEDEFAULT,//how much downwards
                      800,//CW_USEDEFAULT,//width
                      500,//CW_USEDEFAULT,//height
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      hInstance,
                      NULL);

// Find out if the window was created
if( !hWnd ) // If the window was not created,
    return FALSE; // stop the application

// Display the window to the user
ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);// SW_SHOWNORMAL);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);


///CREATING THE WINDOW CLASS FOR YOUR POP WINDOW:
const char g_szClassName2[] = "invisWindow";//name of the window class
WNDCLASSEX invisWindowClass;
HWND invisHWnd;

invisWindowClass.cbSize         = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
invisWindowClass.style          = 0;
invisWindowClass.lpfnWndProc    = WndProcedure;//WndProc;//WNDPROC; //WndProcedure;
invisWindowClass.cbClsExtra     = 0;
invisWindowClass.cbWndExtra     = 0;
invisWindowClass.hInstance     = hInstance;///u might have to get this, but that isn't too hard xD
invisWindowClass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
invisWindowClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
invisWindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
invisWindowClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
invisWindowClass.lpszClassName = g_szClassName2;
invisWindowClass.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

RegisterClassEx(&invisWindowClass);

while( GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) )
{
         TranslateMessage(&Msg);
         DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}

return 0;

}
```

the code I have for when I click the button "which will make the window pop up" is:

```
            case IDC_POPUP:
            {


                const char g_szClassName2[] = "invisWindow";
                const char WndName2[] = "invisible Window";

                HWND invisWindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0,
                      g_szClassName2,
                      WndName2,
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                      200,//CW_USEDEFAULT,//how much to the right
                      200, //CW_USEDEFAULT,//how much downwards
                      800,//CW_USEDEFAULT,//width
                      500,//CW_USEDEFAULT,//height
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      hInstanceSaved,
                      NULL);

                if( !invisWindowHandle ) // If the window was not created,
                    return FALSE; // stop the application

                ShowWindow(invisWindowHandle, 3);// SW_SHOWNORMAL);
                UpdateWindow(invisWindowHandle);

            }
            break;
```

Now why am I not getting a new empty popup window but rather a copy of my main program window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some uncertainty about the window procedure for the 2nd window. Did you provide a WndProcedure function for it? Does that WndProcedure handle the WM_PAINT message? You have to have the WM_PAINT handler so you can see something.

Comment: OH, do I have to make a neww WndProcedure function for each new window I make?

Comment: If I have to add another WndProcedure to be able to make this other window, then I have a concept doubt: the while loop that uses GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) to find any change of events... it eventually dispatches a message to the WndProcedure.... then if I have 2 WndProcedures, wouldn't there be a problem here? how would the DispatchMessage(&Msg) function know which of the 2 WndProcedures is the correct to send to? Am I missing something here xD?

Comment: You need a WndProcedure for each window class that you register, not for each window. All messages contain an HWND. The message is dispatched to the WndProcedure that is responsible for the HWND.

Comment: @SchottMcP-MVP: Scott, did anyone ever tell you you are awesome xD? Ur the mann, simple and precise answer

Comment: So if I want to have like, 10 child windows, I would declare all of them in the WinMain function (by declare I mean make there respective WNDCLASSEX classes and register them), and I would then make a window procedure for eachhh one, correct?

Comment: It is rarely necessary to register so many classes. If the 10 windows are similar they could all use the same wndclass. Think of the wndclass as representing a type of window, not just one window. The window procedure receives an HWND so it can have code for handling many similar child windows.

Comment: Ok so if I make 2 windows, and both of them use the same WndProc, I am guessing they will all HAVE to contain the same buttons, child windows, etc, since the case statement that cointains WM_CREATE will be run for both windows, correct?

Comment: No, they only HAVE to use the same parameters that are in the shared wndclass. If they contain buttons etc. they can usually use the predefined dialog class. Learn about dialogs (DialogBox and CreateDialog).

Comment: K, cause I did eventually find out that the reason I had 2 identical windows pop up was because i used the same WndProcedure when declaring it in the lpfnWndProc field of the WNDCLASSEX STRUCTURE. If I were to make 2 windows using the same WNDCLASSEX STRUCTURE, and since both of them would be using the same WndProcedure, how would I go about preventing one of them from creating the same buttons as the other one (which is currently happening when I use the CreateWindowEX function since both windows go through the same case WM_CREATE statement)?

Comment: The window procedure receives an HWND so it can have code for handling many similar child windows. The HWND tells it which window the message is for.